# open2: exec of lzma -c0 failed a internal-package Error 2 while building in Theos

Tags: theos

I keep getting make: * [internal-package] Error 2 when trying to build a tweak I'm working on. Ive never had this issue before, and its not specifying whats wrong. Here is what it says:

> yinyongzhen@eagle:Desktop/tingtweak ‹master*›$ make package
>   Making all for tweak tingtweak…
>   make[2]: Nothing to be done for `internal-library-compile'.
>   Making stage for tweak tingtweak…
>   dm.pl: building package`com.yz.tingtweak:iphoneos-arm' in `./packages/com.yz.tingtweak_0.0.1-1+debug_iphoneos-arm.deb'
>   open2: exec of lzma -c0 failed at /Users/yinyongzhen/theos/bin/dm.pl line 113.
>   make: *** [internal-package] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Try running the lzma command in terminal, if it's missing, you need to:

```
brew install xz
```

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the same issue, make sure `dpkg` is installed on your machine. It is require for `Theos`. Installing it will get rid of the error with lzma (it seems to be part of).

```
brew install dpkg
```